# Vacuum dry run for delta tables

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

Currently we have a scheduled job which does vacuum of all our delta tables based on an interval.

Is it advisable to do vacuum dry run first and see if there is data to be vacuumed and then do a vacuum if required ?

Or, it does not make any difference interms of efficiency/performance to run vacuum dry run first and then do a vacuum ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Both the dry run and actual execution of `VACUUM` require Delta Lake to *identify* up to 1000 files that can be removed. Therefore, if a table does not have any files that qualify, the process of identifying files for deletion takes the same amount of time.

Furthermore, as discussed in this [databricks community thread](https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/how-does-running-vacuum-on-delta-lake-tables-effect-read-write/m-p/25247), when actually performing `VACUUM` against a table, do note that it does not have any performance impact to the table or any running queries against it during or after the operation; this is because VACUUM is only touching files that are no longer being referenced.